# json file not loading in python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried working on data.json file, to make a English dictionary, but when I tried searching for a word in the file ,it is showing None instead of its meaning

### CODE

```
import json

data= json.load(open("data.json"))

def ta(w):
    if w in data:
        return data[w]
wo=input("enter a word")
print(ta(wo))

enter code here
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\arsh\python practice> python app1.py
enter a word rain
None
```

expected output :
meaning of word that I searched,

> data.json link: https://files.fm/u/8hs5kzz2

can u help?

Comment: Show us the json file

Comment: You should show an example of data in `data.json`. Are you sure it is correct JSON? Are you sure that "rain" is defined in `data.json`?

Comment: Your code looks for "w" in the first level keys of the data.json, not in the values. Is that what you are trying to do? As others have pointed out, please share an example of the content in your data.json.

Comment: Instead of the function `ta`, you could use `data.get(w, "(no translation)")`. Maybe then it would be clearer why you see `None`, which is because `ta` returned `None` after it didn't go into the `if` branch.